# Install Multiple version of Cuda

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, cuda

I have an ubuntu 18.04 VM system with Cuda 10.2 already installed.
I have to run a training of a coda on a GPU, but when I run it I get some errors like:

```
Could not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64:
```

So I think I have to install Cuda 10.0.
Is it possible to have multiple version of Cuda installed? How can I add Cuda 10.0?

I want to run my training on Nvidia GPU

Edit: I succeed Installing Cuda 10.0, downloaded Cudnn 7.4.2, extracted the .tgz file in the cuda-10.0 folder. Now I got this:

I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0

I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7

E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR

E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR

how can I solve this?

Comment: i think u can only install the higher version.( there should be an error) at least i can remember in windows but having multiple versions is fine.

Answer (score 1):

CUDA supports installation of multiple versions at the same time. Here is the CUDA 10.0 download archive link: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive

Once you have installed CUDA, you can specify for your code to look for CUDA 10.0 libraries by defining environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64`.

Comment: also, if you are installing an "older" version of CUDA than one you already have, keep your "newer" GPU driver.  Deselect the option to install any older driver.  The rest of the "older" CUDA toolkit will work fine with your "newer" GPU driver.